# Changing color of each selected feature based on expression using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, vector-layer

Code below changes the color of all the selected features based on the last condition it satisfied instead of changing the color of the feature which satisfied the condition.

```py
for f in FEATURES:

    total = f['parkeer_approx']
    alloted = parking_capacity[f.id()-int(1)]['parking_capacity']

    print(total,alloted)

    if total == alloted:
        print('in red')
        iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor(QColor("red"))

    elif alloted > 0 and alloted < total:
        print('in orange')
        iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor(QColor("yellow"))

    else:
        print('in green')
        iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor(QColor("green"))
```

What I want is to change the color of each selected feature separately based on the conditions defined in the code above.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Don't think it's possible to have more than one selection colour at any time. The easiest would be to set a style for the layer such as a rule-based style and set your expressions with your chosen colour. Perhaps this post might help: [How to programmatically set a rule-based renderer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86770/how-to-programmatically-set-a-rule-based-renderer-in-qgis)

Comment: @Joseph  is it possible to apply rule-based style on selected features only? If yes then how?

Comment: In QGIS 3, there is a function in the rule-based style called `is_selected()` which checks if the feature is selected. You could set up an `if` expression to apply a style if the feature is selected or not. I don't think this function is avialable in QGIS 2 though.

Comment: ok ok ,Btw thanks for the help though @Joseph

Comment: No problem, good luck :)

Comment: Yup i'll try to figure out something if i can...